Import Google Map into QGIS?
How do I import custom Google Maps (such as these: of the saints in Rome or in Italy) into QGIS?

Open the Google Map in a browser. Click the "⋮" icon and download the KML file. In QGIS, go to Layer → Add Layer → Add Vector Layer and import the KML file. That's it!
